# Stanford Core NLP LexicalizedParser Model

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am new to NLP.
I am trying a sample program with `LexicalizedParser` but am not able to locate the model.

```
String parseModel = "...../models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz";
LexicalizedParser lecicalizedParser = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(parseModel);
```

I have the required `stanford-core-nlp-3.5.2.jar` and the ner jar too in build path of a sample Java application.

I tried referring the absolute path of the core jar and load it but could not. :(

How can I refer to the exact location of this model from my program code?

A big thank you for any help and all help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use maven, make sure you include both of these dependencies in you `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
```

This model `englishPCFG.ser.gz`
is inside package `edu.stanford.nlp.models.lexparser`
that is inside `stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar`

So you should use this path:

```
String parseModel = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz"
```

Comment: I am not using maven for this sample test programme. I have both the libs in my build path libraries. But accessing the model by traversing inside the jar is proving to be tough but to crack. Am I forgetting some basic Java stuff for file access is my worry. I must admit.

Comment: @stanfordNLPHelp In eclipse as a standalone tester program. I have the libraries direct in my lib folder of the java project. I guess I need to change the statement like:
String parseModel = "../edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz" but I am not sure if this model "englishPCFG.ser.gz" is there in the core-nlp jar or i need to include other jars too. In that case which jar exactly.

Comment: What Manos says above is correct, the file is in stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar and you should do String parseModel = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz";