# Stanford CoreNLP Arabic parser in Scala REPL

Tags: scala, stanford-nlp, arabic

I'm playing around with Stanford CoreNLP and am trying to use LexicalizedParser for Arabic in Scala. As a side note, I've gotten the segmenter to work. But I get the error below when I try to create a new LexicalizedParser object. According to other StackOverflow answers, I should need to specify all possible arguments for LexicalizedParser:
[Stanford Core NLP LexicalizedParser Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500572/stanford-core-nlp-lexicalizedparser-model)

Anyone have a clue as to what I need to do? I just want to do the bare minimum to pass a string through the Arabic parser

```
scala> var lp = new LexicalizedParser("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/arabicFactored.ser.gz", new Options())

<console>:33: error: not enough arguments for constructor LexicalizedParser: (
                x$1: edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.Lexicon,
                x$2: edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BinaryGrammar, 
                x$3: edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.UnaryGrammar, 
                x$4: edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.DependencyGrammar,
                x$5: edu.stanford.nlp.util.Index[String],
                x$6: edu.stanford.nlp.util.Index[String], 
                x$7: edu.stanford.nlp.util.Index[String], 
                x$8: edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.Options)
                edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.
Unspecified value parameters x$3, x$4, x$5...
```

I've also tried:

```
var lp = new LexicalizedParser()
             .loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/arabicFactored.ser.gz")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
var lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(
  "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/arabicFactored.ser.gz"
)
```

instead.